# is there an image equivalent to table-responsive

Tags: css, image, mobile, responsive-images

I've used table-responsive to allow scrolling on a mobile so you can scroll just the table sideways.

Is there an equivalent for images?

I'd like to add an image to a page that is full size on mobile screens and the user can scroll JUST THE IMAGE sideways to see all of it without scrolling the page (with doesn't look great in my opinion.

I've tried this, which feels like a bit of a bodge:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="{{$site->url}}" alt="Pic" id="bg-img" onclick = fill() />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With css:

```
#bg-img {
  width: 800px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

I couldn't get the above code to work

I hoped there was something like

```
            <img src="{{$site->url}}" alt="Pic" id="bg-img" class="image-responsive" onclick = fill() />
```

I found an image-responsive class in bootstrap but it didn't do what I'd hoped.

So is the an image equivalent that allows fullsized images to display on mobile screens that scroll like tables do with  table-responsive?

Comment: You can add a div and use CSS to make it wider than the screen. The div could have `overflow-x` so you get a horizontal scroll bar in the div. Then it's just a matter of adding the image inside this div and setting the image width to 100%.

Comment: thank you kokodoko that did the trick.  cool username.